# Easy way to secure connectionstring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

So i remember that my teacher once taught us how to secure connectionstrings in web.config. 
Unfortunately, now when i need to know it, i have forgotten all about it.

I have been looking around in here, and found some different questions regarding this, where all of which seemed to have a slightly complicated solution.

Im asking, because i remember that my teacher secured his password in the connectionstring with just a few signs/glyphs, instead of encrypting the entire string.

So my question is obviously how i can secure (doesn't have to be very strong) my connectionstring in one easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using flags in the connecction string as follows:

```
    <add name="PSystem" 
 connectionString="Server=test;
                   Database=Dev;
                   User ID=@UserID@;
                   Password=#Password#;
                   Trusted_Connection=False;
                   Encrypt=True;" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

then you can have the encrypted user and password as follows:

```
<add key="DB_User" value = [Encrypted Username]>
<add key="DB_Password" value = [Encrypted Password]>
```

Then in code you just replace the flags:

```
    string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PSystem"].ConnectionString;

string user = Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB_User"]);
string password = Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB_Password"]);

_connectionString = _connectionString.Replace("##User##", user).Replace("##Password##", password);
```

For all above, thanks to [Oscar Rivera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141902/oscar-rivera) answer as well. Hope this helps!